# error in getting my array MVC

Tags: arrays, model-view-controller

When I try to print_r($result) its getting the array. 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 6 [0] => 6 [ref] => GSO 646&647 [1] => GSO 646&647 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 7 [0] => 7 [ref] => GSO 962 [1] => GSO 962 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 8 [0] => 8 [ref] => GSO ASTM F 1923 [1] => GSO ASTM F 1923 )

but I'm having an error, Maybe the wrong is in the foreach since it saying invalid supplies for foreach().  Anyone can help me pls? thankyou

Model

```
require_once("DatabaseManager.php");

class Model
{

   public $connection;

   public function __construct(){
      $connection = new DatabaseManager();
      $this->connection = $connection->getConnection();
  }

  public function getAllRecords()  
  {
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM reference";   
      $query = $this->connection->query($sql);
      $result = $query->fetchAll();
      //print_r($result);
  }
}
```

Controller

```
require_once("../model/Model.php");

class Controller
{
   private $model; 

   public function __construct() 
   {
       $this->model = new Model();   
   }

   public function displayAllRecords() 
   {
      $result = $this->model->getAllRecords();
      return $result;
   }
}
```

VIEW

```
require '../controller/Controller.php';

$controller = new Controller(); 

foreach($controller->displayAllRecords() as $records) {
. 
.
}
```

Comment: You have to render or throw something from controller to view.

Comment: What do u mean @SaugatBhattarai ? i tried to put return $result;   still have an error

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 6 [0] => 6 [ref] => GSO 646&647 [1] => GSO 646&647 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 7 [0] => 7 [ref] => GSO 962 [1] => GSO 962 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 8 [0] => 8 [ref] => GSO ASTM F 1923 [1] => GSO ASTM F 1923 )  when I print_r($result);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to return $this->model->getAllRecords(); from your controller displayAllRecords() method like this

```
public function displayAllRecords() 
{
   return $this->model->getAllRecords();
}
```

and

```
public function getAllRecords()  
  {
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM reference";   
      $query = $this->connection->query($sql);
      return $result = $query->fetchAll();
      //print_r($result);
  }
```

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: seems your $query->fetchAll(); method does not return something iterable . try to var_dump it's return value and give me result

Comment: array(15) { [0]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "6" [0]=> string(1) "6" ["ref"]=> string(11) "GSO 646&647" [1]=> string(11) "GSO 646&647" } [1]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "7" [0]=> string(1) "7" ["ref"]=> string(7) "GSO 962" [1]=> string(7) "GSO 962" }

Comment: Im getting a result on var_dump/print_r

Comment: i have changed my first comment. try it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134154/discussion-between-aram810-and-genina-anne-gabuten).

Comment: it works.  so i'm just missing 1 return. I need to return both the result and this one return $this->model->getAllRecords();.. thankyou sir